# Error While i am double clicking on list View

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew8zS.png)

While I am double clicking this error is showing please help me out .

Code:

```
Private Sub removefromlist()
        Try

        If lstvwDetail.Items.Count > 0 Then
            SQL = "select COUNT(*) from Item_Master im join Item_Master_Type imt on im.Item_Type_ID=imt.Entry_id " & _
                  " where imt.Main_Category_Type='FINISHED' and Item_Code=" & Tact_Dll.GetItemCode(lstvwDetail.FocusedItem.SubItems.Item(0).Text) & ""
            CMD = New SqlCommand(SQL, Tact_Dll.Cons)

            If IIf(IsDBNull(CMD.ExecuteScalar), 0, CMD.ExecuteScalar) > 0 And ChkAlltem.Checked <> True Then


                ChkAlltem.Checked = True

                End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What does Tact_Dll.GetItemCode() returns? String or integer.

Comment: Confirm what the method GetItemCode returns please. If it returns a string you will need to put ' ' around it.

Comment: Please parametrize your query, do not concatenate values like this (sql injection). Also, your IIF will call ExecuteScalar twice if there's a value.

Comment: Also please read [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: tact_dll.GetItemCode () returns int ,

Comment: Log/display the content of SQL, it'll help you find the error.

Comment: Yup i got it actually it was happening because of sql query ,
thank you so much all of you to show interest in query ..

Comment: Would be worth posting an answer if you have fixed it. However I can't stress the importance of SQL parameters enough. They are easy to use so I can't understand why people don't.

Answer (score 0):

if this helps, add a single quote after item code in your sql statent. Thus,

```
Item_Code='value'
```